# Can't do sudo apt-get update

Tags: apt, updates

While running  sudo apt-get update  it gives me the following error

```
alika@vilnisi:~$ sudo apt-get update
[sudo] password for alika: 
Hit:1 http: //deb.playonlinux.com precise InRelease
Hit:2 http: //archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease                                     
Ign:3 http: //ppa.launchpad.net/glasen/freetype2/ubuntu bionic InRelease                     
Get:4 http:/ /archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease [83,2 kB]                                                                           
Hit:5 https: //dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu bionic InRelease                                                                                                  
Err:6 http: //ppa.launchpad.net/glasen/freetype2/ubuntu bionic Release                                                                                            
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]
Get:7 http: //archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease [74,6 kB]            
Get:8 http: //archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease [83,2 kB]
Reading package lists... Done                                     
E: The repository 'http:// ppa.launchpad.net/glasen/freetype2/ubuntu bionic Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Comment: @karel is correct; this question has the same problem: glasen/freetype2 doesn't support bionic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possibly coming from an upgrade of Ubuntu, a Software source repositories generate an error because it has no entry for the new Ubuntu 18.04
Here is how to fix it
Open the Gnome Software Properties App with App icon or with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>, type `software-properties-gtk`, <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Then display the **Other Software** Tab
Find the line(s) related to `ppa.launchpad.net/glasen/freetype2/ubuntu`
Uncheck the box will disable the software install source
Validate changes and try again with `sudo apt-get update`
[image]
*example for window of Software Properties*